# Android J4L Charts Usage With more than 10 series values

Tags: android

My Problem is Showing 3D Bar chart With not more than 10 values in one series.
Coming to library what i have used is J4L charts for Graphical reports in my android application. So , when i want to show more series values , am unable to show them in chart only i can show 10 series values.
Hope you people understood.

if anyone used J4L charts in android please tell me how to show more series values . It is very Urgent to me. Hope you people understand.

Thanking you well in advance

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using a **demo** version of j4L charts which is `limited to 10` values only.

Here is the download [link](http://www.java4less.com/charts/chart.php?info=download) where they have clearly mentioned about this limitation.

Hope this will help you.

**Please note that I'm no where related to this software and the link is for resolving the issues(confusion) only.**

Comment: Thanks Who ever it might be, clarified my doubts of its usage. One more Help i want is, please recommend any  Charts that works with android application contianing features like touch, 3d effect etc except artifulbits, Teecharts..... 



Thank you

Comment: Hi, If this is the answer you were looking for, can you please accept it as answer so others can make use of it. Thanks